# JQuery "get" failure (using Google App Engine on the back-end)

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, google-app-engine

What I am trying to do is pretty simple: yet something has clearly gone awry.

On the Front-End:

```
function eval() {
    var x = 'Unchanged X'
    $.get("/",  { entry: document.getElementById('entry').value },
          function(data){
            x = data;
          }
      );

       $("#result").html(x);
    }
```

On the Back-End:

```
class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

  def get(self):
      path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
      if self.request.get('entry') != '':
          #self.response.out.write({'evalresult': self.request.get('entry')})
          self.response.out.write(request.get('entry'))
      else:
          self.response.out.write(template.render(path, {'result': 'Welcome!!'}))



   def main():
      application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)],
                                       debug=True)
      wsgiref.handlers.CGIHandler().run(application)
```

Yet, apparently the function is never being called and #result gets set to 'Unchanged X'.  What am I missing?

**NOTE: The callback is NOT being called.  I have verified this by placing an alert("Test") within the callback function.  Any ideas anyone?**

Comment: Is eval a valid function name since there's already built-in function called that?

Comment: eval is getting called ... but just for kicks I changed the function name: no difference.  Still not working.

Comment: Have you used Fiddler or Firebug to see what is happening with the call. Does it go out, does it come back as something other than a 200?

Comment: I gave up on firebug: it's not being very useful.  Safari 4 has similar features built in and it actually seems to be showing me some error (which is confusing me): 

It has an issue with this tag:

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<font size="3" face="Trebuchet MS">Speak Your Mind:&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><input type="text" size="60" id="entry"/> <img valign="bottom" src='/assets/cognifyup.png' onMouseOver="over()" onMouseOut="out()" onMouseDown="out(); evaluate();" onMouseUp="over()"><br><br> 

And gives me the error: Error: NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: DOM Exception 9

I'm stumped

Comment: actually, I'm using firebug now ... had some wierd problem with it.  Now resolved.  I was able to get $.get() working.  Now, tracking down a $.getJSON() issue.  Even though there is no clear "answer" to this one, I appreciate the hints. Thanks for the help folks!

Comment: By the way ... bonus point to whoever sees the problem in the HTML snipplet above (which was causing the original issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we have the silly mistake:

```
<font size="3" face="Trebuchet MS">Speak Your Mind:&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><input type="text"     
size="60" id="entry"/> <img valign="bottom" src='/assets/cognifyup.png' 
onMouseOver="over()" onMouseOut="out()" onMouseDown="out(); evaluate();" 
onMouseUp="over()"><br><br>
```

Semicolons are required after the calls to `over()` and `out()`  (roger that? *--- sorry couldn't resist*)

Secondly (the much more subtle problem):

If we ever need intend to translate the `get()` into a `getJSON()` call, (which you might have noted was my original intent from the commented python code that returns a dict), then we need to wrap a `str()` call around `self.request.get('entry')`.  Hence,

`self.response.out.write({'evalresult': self.request.get('entry')})`

becomes:

`self.response.out.write({'evalresult': str(self.request.get('entry'))})`

As strings from an HTML field translate to unicode text in Python, at the back-end, we apparently need to convert it to a Python string (as `getJSON()` apparently doesn't like Python's representation of a unicode string -- any ideas why this this is the case anyone?).

At any rate, the original problem has been solved.  In conclusion: any JSON object with a Python unicode string will *not* be accepted as a valid JSON object and will fail silently -- a nasty gotcha that I can see biting anyone using JQuery with Python on the server-side.

Answer (score 2):

`$("#result").html(x);` goes in the `get()` callback

Comment: I don't see why this would matter.  But I tried it:  still not working.

Comment: Note: I added an alert() to the callback so I know for sure that the callback is not even getting called.

Comment: It matters because the $.get runs asynchronously, meaning that the html of the element may be replaced before the callback ever runs

Comment: In my particular context this should be ok for now.  But yeah, good point, I will surely be cleaning this up once I get it working.  My next step is to poke around in firebug.

Answer (score 2):

If the callback is not running you can try changing the $.get into a $.ajax() call, and adding an error callback, to see if the server is returning an error.

Or better yet, check in the "net" panel in firebug to see what the server response is, which might help you track down what the issue is on the back end.

Also once the issue is fixed, you might want to replace the $.get with a simple $().load which would take the data and place it into the div automatically:

```
$('#result').load('/', { entry: document.getElementById('entry').value });
```

EDIT: I suppose the following would be a more jQueryish way of writing it:

```
$('#result').load('/', { entry: $('#entry').val() });
```